# HDMI video output briefly goes dark each time System Settings is launched (Ubuntu 18.04.5)

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, system-settings

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 on a Dell XPS 13 9370 laptop, and I have an external HDMI screen. I have the issue that every time I launch System Settings the screen goes dark for few seconds. It also occur with some other applications - for example when launching SPSS.

To provide some more information, it seems to affect only the external screen. I normally work using only the external screen, however if I have both displays on (built-in and external via HDMI), only the external one goes dark when Settings is launched.

It is not a hugely disruptive as an issue, as after few seconds everything goes back to normal, however it is a bit annoying. I wonder if anyone has an idea about why this occurs, or how could I investigate this further? Thanks!

---

**Edit**: The screen is connected via an USB-c to HDMI adapter (don't actually know the brand of the adaptor but I tried also with an original Dell one like [this one](https://www.ebuyer.com/722526-dell-adapter-usb-c-to-hdmi-vga-ethernet-usb-3-0-470-abry?mkwid=s_dc&pcrid=51508045259&pkw=&pmt=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA7NKBBhDBARIsAHbXCB5WOY8T5lpJetHErbEBX_-nFoAYvdMhPjTwht1HcODtFSSZGRyvXiwaAoqAEALw_wcB) and it gives the same issues). The monitor is an ASUS VP28UQGL, 28 Inch 4K.

**Below are the output of the commands suggested in the comment. I realized that the issue occurs when `xrandr` is called, so it may be related to some randr configuration?
I pasted the output below.**

Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux matteo-XPS13 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.98    59.97    48.00  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2560x1600     59.97  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   640x350       70.07
```

Comment: What is the make/model of the monitor? How are you connecting the monitor? You say via HDMI but I didn't think that laptop has an HDMI port so please edit your original question and state exactly what cable/adaptors are being used (if adaptor then the make/model). Also I suggest you post the results of the following commands: `uname -a` and `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` and `xrandr`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I have added the info.